# ¿Como puedo moverme X caracteres a la derecha a partir de un String en Java?

Tags: java

El siguiente programa lee un archivo txt línea por línea:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(origin),"ISO-8859-1"));

                String strLine;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                    if(strLine.contains("Fecha de Emision: ")){
                        String date = strLine.substring(84,93);
                        String[] parts = date.split("/");
                        try{
                            int day = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
                            if(day < 10){
                                SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
                                String dateString = format.format(new Date(date));
                                String newDate = strLine.replace(date, dateString);
                                writer.write(newDate+"\n");
                            } else{
                            writer.write(strLine+"\n");
                            }
                        } catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
                            System.out.println("Problema al parsear el día de la fecha");
                            return;
                        }
                    } else{
                        writer.write(strLine+"\n");
                      }
                }
                br.close();
```

Si en la línea que está leyendo encuentra el String "Fecha de Emisión" lo que debería venir luego es la fecha propiamente dicha (EJEMPLO: 06/12/2018). Yo estoy suponiendo que la fecha está entre las posiciones 84 y 93

**String date = strLine.substring(84,93);**

pero no siempre es así.

Lo que si es fijo es que la fecha siempre empieza dos espacios después del String "Fecha de Emisión".

**Pregunta:**

¿Como hago para decirle a mi programa que haga eso? Osea, que se mueva dos caracteres a la derecha a partir de "Fecha de Emisión" para poder luego validar el formato de fecha y otras cosas que ya tengo hechas !!!

Desde ya muchas gracias :)

Comment: "String.indexOf()"

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario. Podrías ser un poco más especifico ? Porque no entiendo bien a que te referís. Con el indexOf() que debería buscar ?? El número de la fecha ? Los espacios ?? Ninguno de esos me servirían para encontrar lo que quiero !! No hay una forma de moverse a la derecha con bits o algo así como en C ++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con [String.indexOf()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) debieras poder obtener la posición de la palabra que indicas, y como retorna -1 si no encuentra, se puede reemplazar el `contains`.
Para quedar algo como esto:

```
String toFind = "Fecha de Emision: ";
int position = strLine.indexOf(toFind);
if(position >= 0){
    //para cortar el Date a la posición se le suma el largo del string +1, hasta la posición + el largo del string +1 +10 que es el largo de la fecha.
    String date = strLine.substring(position+toFind.length()+1, position+toFind.length()+11);
    String[] parts = date.split("/");
    try{
        int day = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
        System.out.println("day "+day);
        if(day < 10){
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
            String dateString = format.format(new Date(date));
            String newDate = strLine.replace(date, dateString);
            writer.write(newDate+"\n");
        } else{
            writer.write(strLine+"\n");
        }
    } catch(NumberFormatException nfe){
        System.out.println("Problema al parsear el día de la fecha");
        return;
    }
} else{
    writer.write(strLine+"\n");
}
```

Otra forma de lograrlo sería con [Regex](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), pero lo que te indico debiera servirte si siempre viene así.

Comment: GRACIAS brother :)

Answer (score 1):

Buscas la cadena, te posicionas detrás de ella y lees lo que necesitas:

```
public class Main {
    static private String LABEL = "Fecha de emisión: ";
    static private int DATE_LENGTH = 10; // DD/MM/YYYY

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "En un lugar de la Mancha.... Fecha de emisión: 22/11/2018";

        System.out.println(s.indexOf(LABEL)); // 29

        int index = s.indexOf(LABEL) + LABEL.length();
        System.out.println(s.substring(index, index + DATE_LENGTH));
    }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZDPToQwEIfP8BQTThCVLpzUDYc1oB5AD7sXY4zpQmW7loHQQjRmn8pH8MHYFjgY/8yxne8338ye9vSsbhjui9dhaLqt4DnkgkoJGeUIH7YlFVX6sWl5TxWDtWo5lpCurpIUInCuWb6jUDBgFZf86xMvwVn@ojgqiFeb5DlN7m42txoMFksgBOKYZBl50GVb8/gZ7WteQKUl3Gnk4xPQtpSecbJmCxk5CUKHILqStsZCUC2OWsnXBX/IhSEJAhIugnOjaa3fpWKVX3fK166oBLrS51iwt/sXd1zS80bR8EJ3mzXGz@hnE5xMJ/EFw1LtXO/fcNlt5WjvjgmnU6Dmv93HM/jBPgzDEQ)